# Quarto table caption: does not resolve figure/table references in caption with kableExtra::kbl but does with knitr::kable

Tags: r, quarto, kableextra, caption

I'm using Quarto. I need to refer to other figures and tables *in the caption* of figures and tables. References to other figures/tables in the caption of a table work fine when rendered with `knitr::kable()` but *not* with `kableExtra::kbl()`. But I like some of the extras in `kableExtra`. Is there a way to get references in table captions to work for `kableExtra`?

*Added comment, after initial post:* **I'm rendering to PDF. Just this moment I tried rendering to HTML, and it all works. So there's something about rendering to PDF that creates the problem.**

A complete .qmd document with a minimal example is appended below, but here are highlights. There's already a simple figure displayed, referenced by `@fig-A`.  I set up a matrix in R, called `d_mat`. When I display the matrix as a table using `knitr::kable()`, the reference in the caption is resolved as 'Figure 1', like this:

```
#| echo: FALSE
#| label: tbl-kable
#| tbl-cap: "This is a table with `knitr::kable()`. Compare with @fig-A."

knitr::kable( d_mat )
```

[image]

But when I display the matrix as a table using `kableExtra::kbl()`, the reference in the caption is *not* resolved, like this:

```
#| echo: FALSE
#| label: tbl-kbl
#| tbl-cap: "This is a table with `kableExtra::kbl()`. Compare with @fig-A."

kableExtra::kbl( d_mat )
```

[image]

Is there a fix? Thanks for reading!

Complete .qmd document:

````
    ---
    title: "Table Test"
    ---

    ```{r}
    #| echo: FALSE
    #| label: fig-A
    #| fig-cap: "This is a figure. Compare with @tbl-kable."
    #| fig-pos: "!tbph" # for LaTeX floating figures
    
    plot( 0 , 0 )
    ```
    
    ```{r}
    #| echo: FALSE
    d_mat <- matrix( 1:12 , nrow=3 ,
                     dimnames=list( Rows=c("R1","R2","R3"),
                                    Columns=c("C1","C2","C3","C4") ) )
    ```
    
    ```{r}
    #| echo: FALSE
    #| label: tbl-kable
    #| tbl-cap: "This is a table with `knitr::kable()`. Compare with @fig-A."
    
    knitr::kable( d_mat )
    ```
    
    ```{r}
    #| echo: FALSE
    #| label: tbl-kbl
    #| tbl-cap: "This is a table with `kableExtra::kbl()`. Compare with @fig-A."
    
    kableExtra::kbl( d_mat )
    ```
    
    **The caption of @fig-A resolves the reference to the table.** 
    **The caption of using `knitr::kable` in @tbl-kable resolves the reference to the figure.**
    **The caption of using `kableExtra::kbl` in @tbl-kbl does *not* resolve the reference to the figure.**
````

Comment: **P.S. I'm rendering to PDF. Just this moment I tried rendering to HTML, and it all works. So there's something about rendering to PDF that creates the problem.**

Comment: Hard to say, it's working for me and rendering to `pdf` as expected.

Comment: @Grzegorz Sapijaszko: What latex engine are you using? Other pdf settings? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing special, texlive 2023 installed from CTAN; details of session in answer below. LaTeX source generated by quarto and pdfLaTeX log in http://www.sapijaszko.net/up/aaa.zip - hope it helps. In the very past, in knitr/rmarkdown times prior to quarto, there were issues with the sequence of included packages in `.tex` files, as it was included by knitr, LaTeX class itself and who knows what else. Some of the packages were included in preamble 3 times, not necessary in proper order. That's might be a source of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answers is just an extension of comments. All source files/logs are available under http://www.sapijaszko.net/up/aaa.zip

[image]

```
==> quarto preview aaa.qmd --to pdf --no-watch-inputs --no-browse



processing file: aaa.qmd
                                                                                                            
output file: aaa.knit.md

pandoc 
  to: latex
  output-file: aaa.tex
  standalone: true
  pdf-engine: xelatex
  variables:
    graphics: true
    tables: true
  default-image-extension: pdf
  
metadata
  documentclass: scrartcl
  classoption:
    - DIV=11
    - numbers=noendperiod
  papersize: letter
  header-includes:
    - '\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}'
  block-headings: true
  title: Table Test
  

Rendering PDF
running xelatex - 1
  This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex)
   restricted \write18 enabled.
  entering extended mode
  
running xelatex - 2
  This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex)
   restricted \write18 enabled.
  entering extended mode
  

Output created: aaa.pdf
```

And pandoc version:

```
sapi@l7480:~/projekty/test$ pandoc --version
pandoc 2.17.1.1
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.22.2.1, texmath 0.12.4, skylighting 0.12.3.1,
citeproc 0.6.0.1, ipynb 0.2
User data directory: /home/sapi/.local/share/pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2022 John MacFarlane. Web:  https://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is no
warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.
```

Comment: Thank you for the details. I've updated RStudio 2023.12.1 402, R 4.3.2, all R packages (e.g., tinytex 0.49, kableExtra 1.4.0, knitr 1.45), Quarto 1.3.450, and Pandoc 3.1.11.1. I get identical processing report as yours (pandoc, metadata, rendering pdf). *But kbl still does not resolve the figure reference in a table caption. Argh...*

Comment: what about `kableExtra::kbl(d_mat, escape = FALSE)` or `Compare with \\@fig-A.` in caption?

Comment: Thank you again, but unfortunately neither of those works alone, nor when combined together.

Comment: Interesting.. Could you set up `keep-tex: true` and check the `.tex` file around `\caption{\label{tbl-kbl}This is a table with \texttt{kableExtra::kbl()}.
Compare with Figure~\ref{fig-A}.}`? And `keep-md: true` as well and have a look on `.md` file.

Comment: In my .tex file, @fig-A is not resolved for tbl-kbl:  `\caption{\label{tbl-kbl}This is a table with \texttt{kableExtra::kbl()}. Compare with @fig-A. }`  But it is for tbl-kable: `\caption{\label{tbl-kable}This is a table with \texttt{knitr::kable()}.
Compare with Figure~\ref{fig-A}.}`

Comment: And in the .md file, both captions use @fig-A, but the .cell-output-display is in pipe notation for kable and in latex notation for kbl.  Which inspired me to try this: `kableExtra::kbl( d_mat , format="pipe" )`. **And it works!** But I don't know if that will work when adding bells and whistles...

Comment: Congrats :). The last sort of silly idea would be to use `\ref{}` directly, like `Compare with Figure \\ref{fig-A}.` It works, but c'man.. And setting format should work: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html#kable-formats. Just by curiosity, what's the output of `getOption("knitr.table.format")`?

Comment: Unfortunately, `format="pipe"` messes up other things, like math typesetting in cells that need `escape=FALSE`, and floating the position of the table on the page. So, I think I will end up using `\\ref{fig-A}` explicitly. Thank you very much for your engagement with this question!